# Detect original relaying party application

Tags: acs

I want to authenticate user from RP1 and RP2 applications against ACS and my custom STS provider. I need to know from which application RP1 or RP2 a user came from. Is it possible and how to do it?

I think it is trivial without using ACS but how to do it with ACS.

Answer (score 1):

In a federation chain, an STS is theoretically only aware of its neighbors (in this case, your IdP is only aware of ACS) and therefore you can't do this. The only officially supported way to be able to do this is to register the same physical STS as two different logical identity providers in ACS (e.g. http://myidp.com/rp1 and http://myidp.com/rp2).

In practice, however, you can do this another way, though this manner is officially unsupported. The following assumes you're using WS-Federation for your custom IdP, though you can do something similar for other protocols as well. ACS encodes all the data from the original request, including the realm and reply addresses, encoded using [Base64UrlEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokenencode.aspx) in the `wctx` parameter of the WS-Federation response. You can decode the context in the following manner:

```
SignInRequestMessage message = WSFederationMessage.CreateFromUri(Request.Url); 

byte[] bytes = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(message.Context);

string decodedContext = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

This will give you a set of name/value pairs, two of which will be `rm=<realm>&ry=<reply>`, which will be the realm and reply addresses of your original RP.

As I mentioned above, though, beware that this is not officially supported and that the format of this context string may change in the future.

Comment: Yet another approach, that's probably safer, is to download the IdP's login URL using identity provider metadata to host a custom HRD page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185963.aspx). On that page, you can add an additional query parameter to the identity provider's sign-in URL that identifies the RP.

Comment: I posted a more detailed reply to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097275/passing-url-parameters-from-azure-acs-to-my-custom-identity-provider/15100131#15100131