# How to map identity provider claim value to/from identity provider registered in Azure ACS?

Tags: azure, acs

Azure allows us to retrieve a list of registered identity providers by getting:

```
https://YourNamespace.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/metadata/IdentityProviders.js?
    protocol=wsfederation&
    realm=YourAppRealm&
    reply_to=YourAppReturnURL&
    version=1.0
```

When a user sign in we get an *identity provider claim* that identifies which provider that was used for authentication.

The problem is that the `IdentityProvider.js` resource does not tell us which *identity provider claim* that will be used.

For example:

- **Windows Live ID** use the claim value `uri:WindowsLiveID`
- **Google** use the claim value `Google`
- An **ADFS** identity provider may use a claim value like `http://adfs.mycompany.com/adfs/services/trust`

I need to be able to map to/from identity provider claim values and the identity providers listed by `IdentityProviders.js`.

The reason for this is that I need to allow permissions to be assigned to users identified by a particular identity provider. To make it easy for the user I want to give them a list of identity providers to choose from (i.e. by presenting data fetched from `IdentityProviders.js`). However, the actual assignment must be made using the identity provider claim value since that's what identifies the provider.

Is this possible? Are there any workarounds?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Interesting question! Just thinking out loud - Since you configure identity providers allowed through ACS (or in other words, arbitrary identity providers are not allowed), can't you store this mapping in your database? So if the claim value returned as `uri:WindowsLiveID`, you could map that to `Windows Live ID` in your database.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible. However, I am developing a platform that host multiple separate instances (databases) and I wish to minimize the amount of work that has to be done to initialize/setup each instance. All/many instances use the same ACS namespace, so it would be good if I could, for example, add a new identity provider in ACS without having to configure each instance just for this mapping thing...

Comment: Please see if this approach helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097275/passing-url-parameters-from-azure-acs-to-my-custom-identity-provider.

Comment: Thanks. But that only allows me to pass data to the identity provider and have that posted back to me when authentication completes. I'm not able to actually store any information for the identity provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IdentityProviders.js isn't meant for this purpose which is why you're having this issue. The simplest solution is to hard-code these values in your app. If you don't want to do that, you can get these values via the OData Management Service. For each Identity Provider you find via the management service, the IdentityProvider claim value will be idp.Issuer.Name, while the value listed in IdentityProviders.js will be idp.LoginLinkName (or idp.DisplayName if LoginLinkName isn't specified).

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your own values for identity provider by using "Rule group -> "choose one" -> "Add", then leave "input claim ..." as any/any and configure output claim type with same custom claim type for each identity provider, for example:

```
"http://mycustomtype.com/usethisclaimvalue" + "uri:WindowsLiveID"
```

for Windows Live.

Then you can use this added claim as a source for switch operator inside application.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this last week and couldn't find a way to match the value in the claim to the value in IdentityProvider.js. I landed up looking for specific values. The only thing I can suggest is some resource/code that understands the mapping. I was just looking for a specific one and landed up doing something like this:

```
return (HttpContext.User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity).Claims
.First(x => x.Type ==  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider").Value
.Contains("Google")
```

I searched high and low for the data, but couldn't find it. If you do, please submit an answer, I would also like to know

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was by creating a custom rule in the ACS for each of my Identity Providers where I hard coded the output value to match the name value from the IdentityProvider.js. This way, the hard coded values are in the ACS and are not application specific in case you have multiple applications.

Here is an example of how I set up a rule. - http://screencast.com/t/jfDqX0cqu